# How to count positive and negative sentences from Twitter, from many time zones

Tags: scala, twitter, spark-streaming

I use spark-stream to stream tweets and Cassandra for save them by Unix timestamp. I analyze positive, negative sentences and count them per day

**Problem:**
It is difficult to process data from different time zones. The start of a day in GMT+7 is very different from the start of the day in GMT+12.

**Example**

(I'm so sorry about information and it hard to explain)

> In UTC => start day is 2017-03-21T16:50:00Z so I can count sentence in
>   7 hours 10 minute before end of the day
>
> but In some time zone(same time) => start day is 2017-03-21T23:53:00Z
>   so I can count sentence in 7 minute before end of the day

I think I solved this by creating a table per time zone, and I think it is not the best solution.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: If your requirement is to count "per day", how do you define the "day", i.e. when does your "day" start? Is it from 00:00 to 23:59 in some timezone? In the UTC time zone? Explain the requirements first.

Comment: You need to add more information on what exactly you are doing to get a specific answer - but generally speaking you should normalize all the time stamps to a common timezone - usually that would be done by using the milliseconds since 1970 (unix timestamp) in UTC - so map over the timestamps, use Scala to convert to UTC and then feed that as the time into Spark streaming

Comment: Agreed you need to pick a "Day" or use "LocalDate" for each timezone.

Comment: It makes sense to count the tweets in each time zone separately, from 00:00 to 23:59 in each separate timezone. This makes sense because (most) people do not tweet at night, so you get to compare number of tweets per day across timezones. But your days will not start at the same UTC moment. Each day will start at 00:00 in its own timezone, and that is ok.

Comment: @radumanolescu, database is too large. I don't want to do that